# import class from relative path in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, importerror

Based on the below project structure how do I import Foo class in example1.py file?

```
question-project
- src
    - models
        # this folder is deemed package so init file is prsent 
        - __init__.py
        # Foo.py class contains Foo class that could be used by scripts located inside examples and releases folders
        - Foo.py
    - examples
        # this folder only contains script files and init file is not present
        - example1.py
        - example2.py
    - releases
        # this folder only contains script files and init file is not present
        - 0.0.1.py
        - 0.0.2.py
- tests
    - Test_Foo.py
```

Foo.py

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def hello(self):
        print("Foo hello!")
```

example1.py

```py
from ..models.Foo import Foo
x = Foo()
x.hello()
```

The error I am getting when trying to run example1.py file:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/question-project/src/examples/example1.py", line 1, in
>
> from ..models.Foo import Foo
>
> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Is the file in `models` named `__ini__.py` or `__init__.py`? To solve this problem, put an `__init__.py` file in `src`.

Comment: You can use - `models.Foo import Foo`

Comment: @MattDMo Apologies for confusion, file is named __init__.py, placed another __init__.py file into src folder but still same error received.

Comment: @PravashPanigrahi when trying `from models.Foo import Foo` getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'`

Comment: Then you need to set the source root path as `src` on your IDE and then try using `from src.models.Foo import Foo`

Comment: @PravashPanigrahi ok that has worked on PyCharm but how do I make it work running it from the command line on linux? as right now I'm executing the following `python src/examples/example1.py` and resulting in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'`

Comment: You'll probably need to add it to `sys.path`.

Comment: You can add that in your `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/your_project_path/src`

Comment: @PravashPanigrahi this strangely only works when I have only a single project path added. If this variable contains multiple paths separated by `:` it no longer is able to import module

Comment: @MattDMo added `import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path

two_up = Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1]
sys.path.append(os.path.join(two_up))` to the example1.py file and it worked. Is there possibly a more elegant way of doing it?

Comment: @Martin that's actually probably one of the best ways of doing it.